# How to fill html "option" tag with data from database in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I don't understand why information from database isn't showing in html dropdown list. I have watched many videos and tutorials, but something going wrong. Department table isn't empty. I'm using SQLite.

**Here is my html template — [click](https://pastebin.com/JpewmDaT)**

And also:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Department(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Отделы'
    
    department_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Отдел', max_length=40, editable=True, unique=True)


    def str(self) -> str:
        return self.department_name



class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Участники'
    
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Имя', max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Фамилия', max_length=40)
    rfid_mark = models.CharField(verbose_name='RFID', max_length=8, editable=True, unique=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)


    def str(self) -> str:
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm
from .models import Department


def create(request):
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'passage/registration.html', context)


def index(request):
    query_results = Department.objects.all()

    context = {'query': query_results}
    return render(request,'passage/registration.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'rfid_mark', 'department']
```

**urls.py** (project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('sign_up', include('passage.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root =settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**urls.py** (app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.create, name='user create'),
]
```

Comment: Please add your HTML template

Comment: There is a link on top of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you all refreshing to the wrong field as model has no `department_id`. , you were missing the value of the option.

The template shall be as below.

```
{% for result in query %}
      <option value='{{ result.id }}'>{{ result.department_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you queried from Department Model.

See that you are trying to print `{{ result.department_id }}`.

But in the department model, you can access the id with just `{{ result.id }}` or `{{ result.pk }}`.